# Is there a git command that returns 0 or 1 (for example) that will tell me if a file in a working directory has been modified?

Tags: git, diff

I'm looking for a clean, simple way. I could do something like:

`if [ "$(git-diff filename | wc -l)" != "0" ]; then ...`

But I was looking for something more like

`if git-diff filename; then ...`

Something standard that was a documented feature.

It seems like something git might have built in but I haven't been able to find anything like that.

Comment: You need to specify "modified with respect to what": there are typically three of what I call "active" copies of each file. One is the `HEAD`-commit copy, one is the index copy (staged for the next commit, maybe identical to the `HEAD`-commit copy and therefore won't be listed in `git status` as "staged", even though it is actually in the staging area), and the third is the working tree copy. You're suggesting that we compare the working tree copy: that's like asking if Fred uses the same pronouns: ok, but *same as who else?*

Answer (score 2):

I often use `git status --porcelain <filename>` to know, if the file is modified.

As result you can become multiple answers:

- *`nothing`*: The file is tracked and have *no* changes (not modified)
- `M <filename>`: File is tracked and also modified
- `A <filename>`: New created file, where is in stage area (`git add <filename>`, ready for first `git commit`)
- `AM <filename>`: New created file, where is in stage area (`git add <filename>`, ready for first `git commit`) but have new changes local
- `?? <filename>`: File is not tracked, but modified

With `git status --porcelain` you can simple check with the `if`-statement which result the current file emit, and react accordingly.

Comment: `??` just means *untracked*, nothing more. Meanwhile, consider using `--porcelain=v2` here, to get more output that's easier to machine-parse. If you get `M` for instance you might not notice that space-M and M-space are different statuses telling you different things; with `v2` output you'll get `.M` or `M.` as appropriate here.